# '[Class name]' does not name a type in C++

Tags: class, compiler-errors, declaration

I am programming a graph using a list of lists. For that, I have two classes, and each one of this classes has a pointer to another object of the same class and a pointer to the object of the second class. Here is the code:

*File V.h:*

```
#ifndef VERTICEPUNT_H
#define VERTICEPUNT_H

#include "A.cpp"

typedef char E;

 class V
{
    public:
    E etiqueta;
    V* siguiente;
    A* primera;  //<- Error: 'A' does not name a type

    V();
    ~V();
};

#endif // VERTICEPUNT_H
```

*File V.cpp:*

```
#include "V.h"

 V::V()
{
     etiqueta = ' ';
     siguiente = 0;
     primera = 0;  //<- Error: 'primera' was not declared in this scope
}

 V::~V()
{
    delete primera;
    delete siguiente;
}
```

*File A.h:*

```
#ifndef ARISTAPUNT_H
#define ARISTAPUNT_H

#include "V.cpp"

typedef int P;

 class A
{
    public:
        P peso;
        V* vertice;
        A* siguiente;

         A();
        ~A();
};

 #endif // ARISTAPUNT_H
```

*A.cpp:*

```
#include "A.h"

 A::A()  //<- Error: 'A' does not name a type
{
     peso = 0;
     siguiente = 0;
     vertice = 0;
}

 A::~A()  // <- Error: 'A' does not name a type
{
    delete siguiente;
}
```

How would I be able to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message means that the class name is not in scope. `V.h` should not include `A.cpp`, it should include `A.h`. Same goes for `A.h` inclusion of `V.cpp`.

In general, you never want to `#include` a CPP file - from a header or from another CPP file. Only `.h` header files are designed for inclusion by preprocessor.

In case of circular definitions like this, you should forward-declare the class the pointer to which you are defining, and forego inclusion of that class's header:

```
#ifndef VERTICEPUNT_H
#define VERTICEPUNT_H

class A; // <<== Forward declare the class.

typedef char E;

 class V
{
    public:
    E etiqueta;
    V* siguiente;
    A* primera;

    V();
    ~V();
};

#endif // VERTICEPUNT_H
```

Comment: I tried that, and it fixes the errors. However, I get a couple of warnings, like possible problems when invoking ~V, and a invalid use of that class.

Comment: @J-orgeMataVillalobos You have the same issue in both files, so you need to implement a similar change in both places.