# 'ClassName' does not name a type

Tags: c++

I have seen similar answers, but I don't seem to be able to solve mine just by looking at these for example ( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133250/does-not-name-a-type-error-in-c) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333934/class-name-does-not-name-a-type-in-c) one for example).

So, I am having that .

**A.h**

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_CLASS_NAME
#define INCLUDE_CLASS_NAME

#include <B.h>

using namespace C;

D::DPtr myvariable;  <-- Error in here

#endif
```

In the include **B.h** I have this :

```
namespace C{
namespace E{

class D
{
  public:
      typedef shared_ptr<D> DPtr;
}

} //end of namespace E
} // end of namespace C
```

Why am I getting this error in the mentioned line :

```
'D'  does not name a type
```

I am including the .h file, which defines the class. What am I missing?

Comment: Why you declared `myvariable` as `mutable`? This concept only applies to class members.

Comment: @Mikhail yes changed that, I was not able to compile up to that point before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol `D` is inside namespace `E`, which is inside namespace `C`, so the fully qualified name is `C::E::D`.

So either:

- Add `E::` to refer to `D` correctly:

  ```
  mutable E::D::DPtr myvariable;
  ```
- Declare `E` in the `using` directive as well:

  ```
  using namespace C::E;
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You missed namespace E...

```
mutable E::D::DPtr myvariable; // should work
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a function that does not exist yet according to the preprocessor. You need to define functions before you call them:

```
int mainFunction(){
    int foo(int bar){ //define function FIRST...
        return bar;
    }
foo(42) //call it later.
}
```

This should get rid of the error.
This does not:

```
int mainFunction(){
    foo(42) //trying to call a function before it's declared does not work.
        int foo(int bar){
        return bar;
    }
}
```