# c++ extern class does not name a type

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to declare a class object as `extern` but am getting the below error:

> ```
> g++ a1.cpp -std=c++11
>
> In file included from b1.h:5:0,
>                  from a1.cpp:2:
> c1.h:6:8: error: ‘b1’ does not name a type
>  extern b1 obj_b1;
>         ^
> ```

I have looked in 
[Issue declaring extern class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910047/issue-declaring-extern-class-object)
and 
['[Class name]' does not name a type in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333934/class-name-does-not-name-a-type-in-c)

and I THINK I am following the steps mentioned there. But couldn't find what's the issue.

Files are :

**a1.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "b1.h"

b1 obj_b1;


int main(){

    //access object from class B
    std::cout << " test  " << std::endl;
    std::cout << " obj_b1 value is   " << obj_b1.value << std::endl;
    obj_b1.value = 6;
    return 0;
}
```

**b1.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_B1
#define CLASS_B1

#include "c1.h"

class b1{
public:
    int value=5;
    int print_value();
};
#endif
```

**b1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "b1.h"

int b1::print_value(){
        std::cout << "value in b1 is " << value << std::endl;
}
```

**c1.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_C1
#define CLASS_C1
#include "b1.h" // this is an attempt to fix issue, but didnt work

extern b1 obj_b1; // Is there a better place to declare this ?

class c1 {
private: 
    int c1_value=10;
    int c1_print_value();
};
#endif
```

**c1.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "c1.h"

int c1::c1_print_value()
{
    std::cout << "in c1 , value is " << c1_value << std::endl;
    std::cout << " obj_b1.value is " << obj_b1.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can not understand why the compiler complains about `b1`, when I have added `b1.h` just above the extern declaration. Can someone help to solve the issue ?

Comment: Remove `#include "c1.h"` from `b1.h`.

Comment: I want to declare and and use c1 class objects inside b1.cpp. Thats the reason to include c1.h inside b1.h.

Comment: Then move it to `b1.cpp`; `b1.h` doesn't use anything from `c1.h`. It's a good habit to only include necessary header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b1.h` includes `c1.h`, and `c1.h` includes `b1.h`. This is is a mess. By using the `#indef`/`#define` combo, you have prevented an infinite recursion, but it is still a mess.

`obj_b1` doesn't have anything to do with `class c1`, so remove `extern b1 obj_b1;` from `c1.h`.

Now `c1.h` doesn't depend on anything in `b1.h`, so you can remove `#include "b1.h"` from `c1.h`.
An for similar reason, you should remove `#include "c2.h"` from `b1.h`.

On the other hand c2.cpp *does* depend on `obj_b1` (assuming `obj1.name` is a typo, and should be `obj_b1.name`), so you should put `extern b1 obj_b1;` in `b1.h` and `#include "b1.h"` in `c2.cpp`.

For some extra cleanup, move `b1 obj_b1;` from `a1.cpp` to `b1.cpp`